# Electron Nedb findOne returns null?

Tags: electron, nedb

I am calling a simple query with findOne, so far the data in users.db is:

```
{"id":40, "is_admin":1,"name":"John Smith"},
{"id":43, "is_admin":1,"name":"Laura Smith"}


// Users
  var users = new Datastore({ filename: 'db/users.db' });
  var id_user = 43;


  console.log("-------------geting users db");
  //
  users.loadDatabase(function (err) {

    console.log("------------- users db loaded--", id_user);

    // find user by id
    users.findOne({ id: id_user }, function (err, a,b,c) {
      console.log(a,b,c); // displays null undefined undefined
    });


  });
```

Any idea why is returning null?

Answer (score 0):

I think function being passed in findOne should take 2 parameters.  First parameter will be  the result of query and 
second parameter will be error if something goes wrong  . First parameter will be Null if there is no match in db .otherwise it should return the match result.

Function(result, error ){

}
It will be you function prototype

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in my app

```
db.findOne({ "c2cId":"292" }, function (err, a,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c); 
});
```

It return one doc and undefined, undefined.
If you use `findOne` I guess you just want to find the first doc, so looking at the 
[doc at](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/)
You can see there is only two parameters `err` and the `doc`
Concerning the null: in your query are you using a variable named id? or is it the key, in last case you should use quotes....